# Кроссплатформенный CSS, для фиксированного элемента

Tags: html, css

Как сделать, чтобы текст показывался на всех устройствах в одном месте?

```
.rexly {
   left: 50%;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
   font-size: 40px;
   background-clip: text;
   color:transparent;
   -webkit-background-clip: text;
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #593dd5, #fc2b00);
   background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, #593dd5, #fc2b00);
   background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, #593dd5, #fc2b00);
   background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, #593dd5, #fc2b00);
   background-image:         linear-gradient(to right, #593dd5, #fc2b00);
}
```

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Как он должен показываться, как он показывается сейчас, что конкретно вас не устраивает, какое именно «одно место» вас интересует? Из просто вброшенного куска CSS неизвестно откуда ничего не понятно

Comment: Думаю, речь идет о размещении фиксированного элемента на странице. Но, данных конечно не хватает.

Comment: Верно. Надо чтобы на разных устройствах текст показывался именно на том месте, где я его поставил допустим на разрешении 1920 на 720, но на 1280 на 720 текст в другом месте.

Comment: Ну так что? Есть предложения?

Answer (score 0):

Указано **относительное** позиционирование, и оно, при разных разрешениях экрана, не может быть на одном и том же месте.
Укажите атрибуты `left` и `top` в пикселях, например:

```
left: 20px; 
top: 20px;
```

Таким образом, элемент на любом устройстве, будет показан в 20 пикселях от левой 
 и верхней границ.